# Pandas pivot Table Multi-Layer Sorting

Tags: python, pandas, pivot

I have given df: (UPDATED):

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
df = pd.DataFrame({"A": ["foo", "foo", "foo", "foo", "foo",
                         "bar", "bar", "bar", "bar","zz","zz"],
                  "B": ["one", "one", "one", "two", "two",
                         "one", "one", "two", "two","xy","zz"],
                   "Name":["Peter", "Amy", "Brian", "Amy", "Amy",
                         "Peter", "Brian", "Peter", "Brian","Brian","Brian"],
                  "Year": [2019, 2019, 2019, 2019,
                         2019, 2019, 2020, 2020,
                          2020,2019,2020],
                  "Values": [20, 4, 20, 5, 6, 6, 8, 9, 9,10,5]})
df_pivot = pd.pivot_table(df, values='Values', index=['Name','A', 'B'],
                    columns=['Year'], aggfunc=np.sum, fill_value=0, margins=True, margins_name="Totals")
```

Once I pivot it in a way I like it looks like this:

```
 Year            2019  2020  Totals
Name   A   B                      
Amy    foo one     4     0       4
           two    11     0      11
Brian  bar one     0     8       8
           two     0     9       9
       foo one    20     0      20
       zz  xy     10     0      10
           zz      0     5       5
Peter  bar one     6     0       6
           two     0     9       9
       foo one    20     0      20
Totals            71    31     102
```

Now the "fun" part begins..

I would like this df pivot table to be sorted on all index columns from left to right based on sum of values.

Let me explain.

Firstly I would like to sort this pivot table by column "Name" in descending order of "Totals" for each name, therefore I would calculate sum for Amy = 15, Brian = 52, Peter= 35.
From this I know that first column should be sorted Brian/Peter/Amy.

Now I do the same for second column "A", but first column "Name" is fixed.

i.e. for name Brian (which is on top) I now calculate totals for column "A" (I want to see whether foo/bar/zz should be first), therefore I calculate that Brian-Foo is equal to 20 and Brian-bar is equal to 8+9 and Brian-zz is 15, therefore we want to have Foo first for Brian in second column... and the same for rest indexed columns.

The output should look like this:

```
Year            2019  2020  Totals
Name   A   B                      
Brian  foo one    20     0      20 
       bar two     0     9       9
           one     0     8       8
       zz  xy     10     0      10
           zz      0     5       5
Peter  foo one    20     0      20
       bar two     0     9       9
           one     6     0       6
Amy    foo two    11     0      11
           one     4     0       4
Totals            71    31     102
```

So long story short, firstly I want to sort first column based on totals for items from that column and I want to fix it, then I want to sort second column for items from that column, but grouped as per first sorting etc.

Can you advise how to do this please?
I appreciate help a lot!

Thanks
Pawel

Answer (score 1):

You can use `groupby.transform` to get the sum within names, then sort with it:

```
df_pivot = (df_pivot.iloc[:-1]
              .assign(sort=lambda x: x['Totals'].groupby(level=0).transform('sum'))
              .sort_values(['sort','Name','Totals'], 
                           ascending=[False,True,False], kind='mergesort')
              .drop('sort', axis=1)
              .append(df_pivot.iloc[-1])
           )
```

Output:

```
Year            2019  2020  Totals
Name   A   B                      
Brian  foo one    20     0      20
       bar two     0     9       9
           one     0     8       8
Peter  foo one    20     0      20
       bar two     0     9       9
           one     6     0       6
Amy    foo two    11     0      11
           one     4     0       4
Totals            61    26      87
```

Comment: Dear Quang Hoang, thank you very much, I have run this on this df and works perfectly, but I did run in on my other df and it doesn't work as expected.
I have modified df in original post so that you can try to run on new df.
As you can see from your code in column "A" for Brian values "zz" are not grouped, but they should be. can you please advise? 

Thank you

Comment: Hello, could you please have a look?

Comment: Use `.sort_values(['sort','Name','A','Totals']` instead of `.sort_values(['sort','Name','A','Totals']`.

Comment: Dear @Quang Hoang,
I have adjusted the formula and also I added 4th dimension for sorting as it would not run, so it's like this: df_pivot = (df_pivot.iloc[:-1].assign(sort=lambda x: x['Totals'].groupby(level=0).transform('sum')).sort_values(['sort','Name','A','Totals'],
                           ascending=[False,True,False,False], kind='mergesort')
              .drop('sort', axis=1).append(df_pivot.iloc[-1]))

but it doesn't seem to work, the df is sorted correctly on first column, but not on the second. Brian-Foo with 20 is in the middle, but should be at top. Can you please advise?

Comment: now that `append` is deprecated (pandas ≥ 2.0.0), [here is a modification of this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/76013474/16343464) to use [`concat`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.concat.html).